# Rails how to get date difference from each loop

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In rails application how to get the days difference of date of the records of an each loop. I have a field named date and I want to extract the difference of days between the descending date of the records.

```
<div id="searchResult">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Guard Name</th>
                <th>Client Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Transfer Date</th>
                <th>Days</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @search.each do |f| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= f.guard.try(:name) %></td>
                <td><%= f.client.try(:name) %></td>
                <td><%= f.sallary %></td>
                <td><%= f.date.strftime("%Y-%b-%d") %></td>
                <td>Date Difference</td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [time_difference](https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference)

you can get it as:

```
<div id="searchResult">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Guard Name</th>
                <th>Client Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Transfer Date</th>
                <th>Days</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @search.each_with_index do |f, i| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= f.guard.try(:name) %></td>
                <td><%= f.client.try(:name) %></td>
                <td><%= f.sallary %></td>
                <td><%= f.date.strftime("%Y-%b-%d") %></td>
                <td><%=TimeDifference.between(@search[i].date,@search[i+1].date).in_years%></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here `@search` is an array and for array we can get result like this: -

```
array[0] - array[1]
```

that is `previous_record.date - current_record.date`

I think it should work.

A simple example is

```
start_time = Time.new(2013,1)
end_time = Time.new(2014,1)

TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_years
=> 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but i did it this way... <%= (@search[i].date.to_date - @search[i+1].date.to_date).to_i %>

Comment: @SantoshAryal yep, but `time_difference` gem gives you nicely result in different ways, you can see its doc.any thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

There is [each_cons](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons) method, which iterates over N following items:

```
records.each_cons(2) do |current, previous|
  date_difference = current.date - previous.date
end
```

Comment: Thanks, well could you please elaborate. My case is bit different. I am generating a report and along with the same query i want to differentiate the date of previous record with the date i provide during query. I modified my question

Comment: You pass ie. Date.new(2018, 1, 18) and you want to get the difference in days for every record with :date field?